# How can i click a button with a custom ID that is not recognized in Javascript? If there is not a name or tag or ID, can it be done?

Tags: javascript, forms, button, click, submit

There is a website I am trying automate using JavaScript to apply a discount code. I need to know an alternative method to get this specific button to submit() or click() it. I already found a way to input a code because there is an ID for that element. However, that is not the case for this button. When i used the data-trekkie-id ID, "apply_discount_button", it wouldn't recognize the ID.

```
    <button name="button" type="submit" class="field__input-btn btn btn--disabled" data-trekkie-id="apply_discount_button" aria-busy="false">
          <span class="btn__content visually-hidden-on-mobile" aria-hidden="true">
            Apply
          </span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">
            Apply Discount Code
          </span>
          <svg class="icon-svg icon-svg--size-16 btn__icon shown-on-mobile" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <use xlink:href="#arrow" /> </svg>
          <svg class="icon-svg icon-svg--size-18 btn__spinner icon-svg--spinner-button" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <use xlink:href="#spinner-button" /> </svg>
```

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting 100% about what you're looking for. But I guess you want to select the button with the custom html5 data attribute (`data-trekkie-id`).

You can select the button in javascript using the following line:

```
const discountButton = document.querySelector('[data-trekkie-id="apply_discount_button"]');
```

It will return the first match with the attribute `data-trekkie-id="apply_discount_button"`.

Then you can listen events on this element by attaching `addEventListener` method.

Like if you want to listen for click event on this element, the code will be:

```
 discountButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
     alert('Discount button was clicked.'); // Replace this line with your code
 });
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for this answer however I am looking for another solution. I want to be able to automate putting a number in the text box (which I have done) and then being able to submit this code. To do that, I needed to get ahold of the button (which you helped me with) but I want to automate the task of clicking the button through code , not listen for a click.

Answer (score 0):

Because of HTMl's flexibility you can create your own attributes and use them  and you want; if you have ever used bootstrap you will see that they add some attributes to html tags
You can do the same.
To capture the click event on the button with the data-trekkie-id attributes, you can we jQuery do something like:

```
$("[data-trekkie-id=apply_discount_button]").click(function(){
  //some stuff
})
```

or simply:

```
$("[data-trekkie-id]").click(function(){
    //some stuff
})
```